# Has many through relationship without classical join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 relevant models : project, tasks and subtasks.

**Project has many tasks and task has many subtasks. 
Accordingly task belongs to project and subtask belongs to task.**

Right now there is no direct connection between project and subtasks. I would like to make one (and have access to things like @some_project.subtasks & @some_subtask.project). I thought to not add the project_id field to subtasks migration, but to **use task model as a sort of 'connection' between projects and subtasks** (since task already has project_id column and has_many relationship with subtasks).

I started by writing **project has_many :subtasks, :through => :tasks** and **subtask belongs_to :project**.

I got the subtasks method on project model, but when I write @some_subtask.project I always get nil. Also, when I use scoping on @some_project.subtasks I always get 'ambiguous column name' error.

I think this is **because I made my relationships wrong.** How to do them right? Also, if adding project_id field to subtasks migration file is the better solution (or something entirely different) by all means let me know.

EDIT: here are the scopes that return column name error ( I have them in lib/ folder, it is a module that is included in task and subtask models)

```
10   # SCOPING
 11   def self.included(base)
 12   
 13     today = Date.today
 14     start_of_day = DateTime.new(today.year, today.month, today.day, 0, 0, 1)
 15     end_of_day = DateTime.new(today.year, today.month, today.day+1, 0, 0, 0)
 16   
 17     base.class_eval do
 18       scope :not_targeted, where(:target => nil)
 19       scope :targeted, where("target IS NOT ?", nil)
 20       scope :targeted_today, where("target > ? AND target < ?", start_of_day, end_of_day)
 21       scope :targeted_after_today, where("target > ?", end_of_day) 
 22       scope :overdue, where("target < ?", start_of_day)
 23     end
 24 
 25   end
```

Those return error when I try to define variables like these in project controller (lines 47 and 51 are to blame for the error). **Basically I need these to pass and return proper records.**

```
 35     @project_tasks = @project.tasks
 36     @project_subtasks = @project.subtasks

 45     @today_tasks = @project_tasks.targeted_today
 46     @today_subtasks = @project_subtasks.targeted_today
 47     @today = @today_tasks + @today_subtasks
 48 
 49     @after_today_tasks = @project_tasks.targeted_after_today
 50     @after_today_subtasks = @project_subtasks.targeted_after_today
 51     @after_today = @after_today_tasks + @after_today_subtasks
```

For example this is the error line 47 returns...

> SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: target: SELECT
>   "subtasks".* FROM "subtasks" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON
>   "subtasks"."task_id" = "tasks"."id" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = 1 AND
>   (target > '2012-06-24 00:00:01' AND target < '2012-06-25 00:00:00')

Here is Project model:

```
  1 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  2              
  3   # RELATIONSHIPS          
  4   has_many :synapses, :dependent => :destroy
  5   has_many :users, :through => :synapses, :dependent => :nullify
  6 
  7   has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  8   has_many :subtasks, :through => :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  9   has_many :discussions, :as => :discussionable, :dependent => :destroy
 10   
 11   #use this when you don't have callbacks
 12   #has_many :tasks, :dependent => :delete_all
 13   
 14   # VALIDATIONS
 15   validates :name, :presence => true,
 16             :length => { :maximum => 50 }   
 17   
 18   validates :description, :presence => true,
 19                           :length => { :maximum => 200, :minimum => 15 }
 20 
 21   # ATTRIBUTE ASSIGNMENT   
 22   attr_accessible :name, :description
 23 
 24   # CUSTOM METHODS         
 25   def belonging_project    
 26     self                   
 27   end                      
 28 
 29 end
```

Here is Task model:

```
  1 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  2              
  3   include SharedModelCode  
  4   # has scoping and validate method
  5 
  6   # RELATIONSHIPS          
  7   belongs_to :project      
  8 
  9   has_many :vesicles, :dependent => :destroy
 10   has_many :users, :through => :vesicles, :dependent => :nullify
 11   
 12   has_many :subtasks
 13   
 14   has_many :discussions, :as => :discussionable, :dependent => :destroy
 15   
 16   # VALIDATIONS
 17   validates :project, :presence => true
 18   validates :name,  :presence => true,
 19                     :length => { :maximum => 50 }   
 20   validates :description, :presence => true,
 21                           :length => { :maximum => 200, :minimum => 15 }
 22   validate :target_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
 23                            
 24   # ATTRIBUTE ASSIGNMENT   
 25   attr_accessible :name, :description, :target, :completed
 26 
 27   # CUSTOM METHODS         
 28   def belonging_project    
 29     Project.find_by_id(self.project_id)
 30   end                      
 31 
 32 end
```

Here is Subtask model:

```
  1 class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
  2              
  3   include SharedModelCode  
  4   # has scoping and validate method
  5 
  6   # RELATIONSHIPS          
  7   belongs_to :task         
  8   belongs_to :project      
  9 
 10   has_many :subvesicles, :dependent => :destroy
 11   has_many :users, :through => :subvesicles, :dependent => :nullify
 12   
 13   has_many :discussions, :as => :discussionable, :dependent => :destroy
 14   
 15   # VALIDATIONS            
 16   validates :name,  :presence => true
 17   validates :task, :presence => true,
 18                     :length => { :maximum => 200 }  
 19   validate :target_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
 20 
 21   # ATTRIBUTE ASSIGNMENT   
 22   attr_accessible :name, :target, :completed
 23 
 24   # CUSTOM METHODS         
 25   def belonging_project    
 26     task = Task.find_by_id(self.task_id) 
 27     Project.find_by_id(task.project_id)
 28   end                      
 29                            
 30 end
```

Comment: re the "ambiguous column"-error: What does your schema look like? As far as I can tell `@project.subtasks` should work fine. As for `@subtask.project` you can add a `project` instance method on Subtask: `def project() task.project; end`

Comment: Ok, I added the scopes and the error message it returns...

Comment: FYI, Rails extends Time with methods like `all_xxx`, where `xxx` can be: `day`, `week`, `month`, `quarter`, `year`. The result is a time range. Combine it with the ActiveRecord's ability to handle ranges and you'll get the ability to do something like: `.where(target: Time.now.all_day)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: target: SELECT "subtasks".* FROM "subtasks" INNER JOIN "tasks" ON "subtasks"."task_id" = "tasks"."id" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = 1 AND (target > '2012-06-24 00:00:01' AND target < '2012-06-25 00:00:00')

is due to how you wrote your scopes, not how you created your relationships. It saying that have a column `target` in *both* the `tasks` and `subtasks` tables.

Rewriting the scope like this should fix at least that error:

```
# tasks targeted today
scope :tasks_targeted_today, where("tasks.target > ? AND tasks.target < ?", start_of_day, end_of_day)

# subtasks targeted today
scope :subtasks_targeted_today, where("subtasks.target > ? AND subtasks.target < ?", start_of_day, end_of_day)
```

When you have the same column name in multiple tables in a join like this, you need to specify which table and column the constraint applies to.

Comment: you got it on the nail! thank you. So if I add these 2 lines to scopes, I'll get the list of all the tasks and subtasks targeted(scheduled) for today?

Comment: I believe so -- though I'm not sure. I'd recommend moving forward and then posting a new question if you have questions after getting a bit further along. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you need belongs_to-like relationship through other table, then use `has_one`. It allows you to specify `through` in its options.

Comment: thanks worked just as I wanted. You know what I need to do to make those scopes up there pass?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this perhaps

```
class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :subtasks, :through => :tasks, :foreign_key => "project_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `:trough` in a belongs_to association. However you can define the grandparent easily:

```
class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
...
  def project
    task.project
  end
...
```

The 'ambiguous column name' error needs more info to solve. Can you attach the scope you've tried?

Comment: I have attached the scopes. Can you please write code you wrote propery, I have trouble reading it... thanks